# How do I run MetaVelvet? The 'Getting Started' instructions don't work as expected

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to improve a metagenomic assembly by running MetaVelvet on my output.  The ['Getting Started' instructions for the MetaVelvet extension](http://metavelvet.dna.bio.keio.ac.jp/MV.html#install) don't produce a Graph2 file, which is required by the MetaVelvet extension.

How do I produce a Graph2 file so that I can run MetaVelvet?

Comment: I suggest editing your question to elaborate on what steps you took and what error messages you saw, if any, to help people figure out how to help you. StackOverflow is better at handling specific issues; questions asking about general tutorials may be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Getting Started' instructions are missing a flag in the velvetg command.  The flag is required if you need to generate a Graph2 file.

Here is the corrected version of those instructions:

> ~$ velvetg out-dir -read_trkg yes -exp_cov auto -ins_length 260

Tip:
If you have ran velveth with multiple k-mers, and therefore have multiple output folders you can use the find command to assemble every one without running the command each time.

Imagine the multiple k-mer velveth output folders start with 'pooled_reads':

> find . -name 'pooled_reads_*' -exec velvetg {} -read_trkg yes -exp_cov auto -ins_length 200 \;

You can also use xargs or a while loop to do this too, but I like the find command.